# Eliminate gap between plot and panel in ggplot theme(panel.background)

Tags: r, ggplot2

My first post - take pity!  Edited as suggested.
The plot below works fine without the final min and max values, except that it leaves a gap between the path plot and the border, which I want exactly at the edge of the map.  My attempt to force the border generates the error

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(987)
x <- runif(20,0,100)
y <- runif(20,0,100)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
ggplot(df)+
 theme_void()+
 geom_path(aes(x,y))+
 scale_x_continuous(limits=c(10,90))+
 scale_y_continuous(limits=c(10,90))+
 theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size=1, fill=NA,
              xmin=10, xmax=90, ymin=10, ymax=90))

Error in element_rect(colour = "black", size = 1, fill = NA, xmin = 10,  : 
           unused arguments (xmin = 10, xmax = 90, ymin = 10, ymax = 90)
```

Comment: Hi Mike. An example data set which you can provide using the function `dput` and a fully reproducible example would bring quality answers faster.

Comment: Dataset is very large.  I saved with dput but I cannot copy and paste into question by editing.  How do I add it to my question?

Comment: It is best to recreate the problem with a small data set, perhaps a sample of 20 rows of your original data: `dput(df[sample(1:nrow(df), 20),])`. Before pasting please verify the problem can be recreated with this sample data.

Comment: Remove limits from `theme` and try to add `expand = c(0, 0)` into `scale_x_continuous` and `scale_y_continuous`.

Comment: Many thanks Adela.  That seems to be working OK.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea by defining `ylim`, `xlim` and `expand` in `coord_cartesian`.

```
ggplot(df)+
  theme_void()+
  geom_path(aes(x,y))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(10,90),
                  ylim = c(10,90),
                  expand = FALSE)+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black",
                                        size = 1,
                                        fill = NA))
```

[image]

this is most likely superior to

```
ggplot(df)+
  theme_void()+
  geom_path(aes(x,y))+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(10,90),
                     expand = c(0, 0))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(10,90),
                     expand = c(0, 0))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black",
                                        size = 1,
                                        fill = NA))
```

[image]

because by setting limits in `scale_x_continuous` the data points outside these limits are completely removed, while by using `coord_cartesian` they are just not seen.

Comment: Thankyou missuse.  I can see that this is better with a few long path lines, but in my actual plot, there are thousands of tiny lines, so they all appear to fit to the boundary in both solutions. I will try to behave in future questions, even if this does need me to learn markdown.